# How to make a multi-column list in Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to convert a page from Flask/Jinja templates to Vue JS?

My Jinja template looks like this:

```
<div class="columwrapper">
  {%- for column in skills|slice(3) %}
    <ul class="column-{{ loop.index }}">
    {%- for item in column %}
      <li>{{ item }}</li>
    {%- endfor %}
    </ul>
  {%- endfor %}
</div>
```

The data looks like this:

```
"skills": [
        "Microsoft Office",
        "Oracle SQL Developer",
        "R (Programming Language)",
        "Visual Basic for Applications (VBA)",
        "SharePoint",
        "InfoPath",
        "Structured Query Language (SQL)",
        "Tensorflow",
        "Tableau",
        "Neo4j",
        "Linux",
        "JavaScript",
        "Python",
        "Flask",
        "Hadoop",
        "Cassandra",
        "Spark"
    ]
```

I want the table to look something like this:

```
    <div class="columwrapper">
        <ul class="column-1">
          <li>Microsoft Office</li>
          <li>Oracle SQL Developer</li>
          <li>R (Programming Language)</li>
          <li>Visual Basic for Applications (VBA)</li>
          <li>SharePoint</li>
          <li>InfoPath</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="column-2">
          <li>Structured Query Language (SQL)</li>
          <li>Tensorflow</li>
          <li>Tableau</li>
          <li>Neo4j</li>
          <li>Linux</li>
          <li>JavaScript</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="column-3">
          <li>Python</li>
          <li>Flask</li>
          <li>Hadoop</li>
          <li>Cassandra</li>
          <li>Spark</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

What is the equivalent way to break up a list into multiple columns?

Comment: is it fixed position to break like that ? I would recommend to use multi dimensional array ..

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Are you asking how to loop through the list to make multiple columns for how to format the hard-coded list into three columns?